# How do I evaluate the first step of a Clojure form?

Tags: clojure, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, clojurescript

If I have the following string containing a valid Clojure/ClojureScript form:

`"(+ 1 (+ 2 (/ 6 3)))"`

How would I evaluate the first "step" of this form? In other words, how would I turn the above form into this:

`"(+ 1 (+ 2 2))"`

and then turn that corresponding form into this:

`"(+ 1 4)"`

Answer (score 3):

You use recursion.

You need to have a function that evaluates the numbers to themselves but if it's not a number you need to apply the operation on the evaluation of the arguments.. Thus

```
(evaluate '(+ 1 (+ 2 (/ 6 3))))
```

This should be treated as:

```
(+ (evaluate '1) (evaluate '(+ 2 (/ 6 3))))
```

When it starts doing your first step several steps are waiting for the results to be done as well.

Note I'm using list structure and not strings. With strings you would need to use some function to get it parsed.

Comment: What's my base case? How could I determine that (/ 6 3) is to be evaluated first?

Comment: Your base case is numeric expressions. `6` evaluates to `6`. Thus `(evaluate '(/ 6 3)) ; ==> ((get-fun '/) (evaluate '6) (evaluate '3))`. You don't need to determine it since the evaluator will always do it's dependencies first.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are great if you want to execute code in steps, but I want to mention that this evaluation can also be visualized using a debugger. See below [Cider's debugger](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/debugging.md) in action:

[image: Visualization of debugging]

By using `cider-debug-defun-at-point` we add a breakpoint on `evaluate`. Then when the `evaluate` definition is evaluated the breakpoint is hit, and we step through the code by pressing `next` repeatedly.

A debugger is very handy when you want to evaluate "steps" of forms.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think of that, but a debugger is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't seem to have cider-debug-defun-at-point in my emacs installation. Is it new?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson Have you added Cider to your configuration? It's [included](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/cider-debug.el#L743). I use Spacemacs with the [Clojure layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/clojure) added. That way I only had to add `clojure` to the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a very basic implementation that does what you're looking for. It would be more common to eval the entire form, but since you're wanting to just simplify the innermost expressions, this does it:

```
(defn leaf?
  [x]
  (and (list? x)
       (symbol? (first x))
       (not-any? list? (rest x))))

(defn eval-one
  [expr]
  (cond
    (leaf? expr) (apply (-> (first expr) resolve var-get)
                        (rest expr))
    (list? expr) (apply list (map eval-one expr))
    :default expr
    ))


(read-string "(+ 1 (+ 2 (/ 6 3)))")
=> (+ 1 (+ 2 (/ 6 3)))
(eval-one *1)
=> (+ 1 (+ 2 2))
(eval-one *1)
=> (+ 1 4)
(eval-one *1)
=> 5
```

This is naive and for illustrative purposes only, so please don't be under the impression that a real eval would work this way.

We define a leaf as a list whose first element is a symbol and which does not contain any other lists which could be evaluated. We then process the form, evaluating leaf expressions, recursively evaluating non-leaf expressions which are lists, and for anything else, we just insert it into the resulting expression. The result is that all innermost expressions which can be evaluated, according to our definition, are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other great answers, here is a simple function that should return the first form to evaluate in a given string:

```
(defn first-eval [form-str]
  (let [form (read-string form-str)
        tree-s (tree-seq sequential? identity form)]
    (first (filter #(= % (flatten %)) tree-s))))
```

Usage:

```
(first-eval "(+ 1 (+ 2 (/ 6 3)))") ;; returns (/ 6 3)
```

`tree-seq` is fairly limited in it's ability to evalute ALL form, but it's a start.